# Write an XML-File with LINQ to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

i`ve got a little problem with LINQ. I read out some information via XML-RPC.
Parsing the Method-Response is no problem, but I dont no how to write the 
Data correctly in a new XML-File.

Here`s my Code so far:

```
var confs = from x in file.XPathSelectElements("//member[name='conferenceType'][value = 'active']"
                        + "/parent::node()/member[name='conferenceName']")
                    select x;

        XElement root = new XElement("Active-Conferences");

        foreach (XElement xConfs in confs)
        {
            var participants = from p in xConfs.XPathSelectElements("//member[name='conferenceName']" +
                                   "/parent::node()/member[name='displayName']")
                              select p;

            root.Add(new XElement("conferenceName", xConfs.Element("conferenceName").Value)
                + new XElement("displayName").Value);
        }

        root.Save("d:/neu2.xml");
```

I want to build a new XML-File which contains all read out conferences (conferenceName) and related participants (displayName)! I got the relation between conferences and displayNames with my query, but dont know how to write this data correctly to a new XML-File, with the format I want... something like this:

[alt text http://www3.pic-upload.de/22.10.09/49moeyej2crj.jpg](http://www3.pic-upload.de/22.10.09/49moeyej2crj.jpg)

Comment: That format is odd - note that "Participants" is at the same level as "conferenceName" in terms of the actual tree hierarchy - so why would you want it to be indented? Did you actually mean to have a "Conference" element with a "name" attribute perhaps?

Comment: The XML is only an example to show what I want to build. My problem is only the LINQ part! I wante the <conferencName>-Tag for the conference-names and the <displayName>-Tag for the related participants, so that I got a new xml-file with all the conferences and their related participants!

Comment: What XML does your code currently produce? As programmers, we're a very precise bunch, so if you could show exactly how you want the output formatted instead of an incorrect example, that might help.

Comment: Hi Dennis,

the problem is solved, I did it a whole other way! My XPath was not correct and I did it with a where-clause, which worked out fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this tool:
[link text](http://net2csgenxlinq.codeplex.com/)

It helps you to write Xml file with Linq to xml ...in c#

Answer (score 1):

give a try to the PasteXmlAsLinq visual studio add-in, here's the url [Visual Studio 2010 Samples for C# 4.0](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Visual-Studio-2010-Samples-31b491f3)

*PasteXmlAsLinq: A Visual Studio addin that automatically converts XML to LINQ to XML.